# I cannot change anything in my wordpress database from within wordpress?

Tags: database, taxonomy, migration, options

So I have set up my database name, user and password in c-panel; these correlate with my wp-config file.

When I change (for example) my email from settings->general setting from wordpress admin, it reverts back to what it was previously, nothing changes.

When I try to activate or deactivate my plugins, the message 'plugin activated' appears above, but the plugin state remains unchanged.

I cannot post pages, I am given this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/greensnd/public_html/wp/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 199

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/greensnd/public_html/wp/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 200
Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post.
```

Really struggling to get to the bottom of this.

I developed my site locally and then moved it to the server. Imported the database. Changed the wp-config.

Whats going on?? :'(

Comment: If you go in through FTP and change the names of the folders, such as adding '-test' to the end of the folder name, or move them up into the wp-content folder, it will disable the plugin.  I'd start there, go one by one and hope you find the culprit.

Comment: did you give your db user the proper read/write permissions when you were setting it up?